# How to make Google Maps Load only Once between tabs in Ionic 1 Tabs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have two tabs: **Maps** and **Places**

The problem is that **every time** I go the **Maps tab**, the Google Maps it is loaded whether is already loaded before. This causes my app to slow down, every time I go to the **Maps Tab**

I tried to make this logic my **MapCtrl**

```
if ($scope.map == undefined) {
    console.log('NO GOOGLE MAP');
    var mapOptions = {
       center: usersLatLng,
       zoom: 15,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); 
    }
} else {
    console.log('HAS GOOGLE MAP');
}
```

The result in the console every time I go to the **Maps Tab** is 'NO GOOGLE MAP'

Is there anyway to **trigger** the else function when the Google Maps is already defined?

Example would be when I move from **MAPS->PLACES->MAPS**, the Google Map won't load anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding **cache:true** in my state.

`.state('tab.map', {
    url: '/map',
    cache:true,
    views: {
      'tab-map': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-map.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
      }
    },
    params: { args: {} }
  })`